# Android Google Play changing name of app

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to change name of application after publishing it in Google Play?
I haven't published it yet but I'm going to do it.

Comment: This should actually be reopened.  It is a valid concern if you submit an application and decide to change the name later for any reason.  It's not really off topic since the name of the application and package name are completely different.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play

Comment: Package name and application name are completely different and should be noted as the above link is based off of package name.

Comment: This should be reopened as it is on topic and a valid question.  Name and package name are separate in Android and have different rules place on them.  The link provided is not related as it refers to the package name and not app name itself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can change the name.  You cannot change the package name.

Comment: As of 2019, it's under Store Presence / Store Listing

Comment: How? Explanation? This shouldn't be the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer.  When creating an Android application, there is an app name and there is a package name.  Changing the package name would result in having to create a new application in the play store.  Changing app name would just change the name of the app.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can.   Login into the Android Developers Console:  http://developer.android.com/distribute/index.html

From the app you want to change from the list of the apps you have submitted.

On the bottom half of the package details tab you will see at Title field which you can update and it will change the name of your app.

Comment: Is it possible even when the app has been suspended??

Answer (score 3):

If you have not published the app yet..then you can go to your project and change the name , sign the apk and upload it again.
You can change the app information at any point of time, without changing the version number of the app.