# App update with different package name into playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I've published an app to the playstore. On the same time, I worked on an update, but the update has a different package name.

Like:

```
Release version 1.0 -> com.domain.packageOne
Release version 1.1 -> com.domain.packageTwo
```

Can I now add packagteTwo without problems to the production phase or will then, the device download both versions? The problem then would be, that the user would have two verions of my app.

Or do I need to change the package name in my project so it matches packageOne? Thanks!

Comment: you have to keep the original package name, google is referencing on that name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing an update for an app, it should have the same package name, and should always be signed with the original signing certificate used when the app was first published.

If you upload your update with a different package name, the play store will treat it as two separate apps, I'm not sure whether or not it will allow the same application name, as viewing in app listings, to be the same, I don't believe it does so you would probably get an error anyway stating that an app with that name already exists.

If the actual application name is also different, then the play store will treat it as two different apps.

If you change your package name to be the same as the original package name, you can update the app as long as you use the same signing certificate as the original app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make an update to your app it has to have the same package name. Just increase the application version

[See this link on how to specify versions on your app](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)