# Creating a new Android app based on a old one

Tags: android, android-build-flavors

I have an Android App that was removed from Play Store due to the new Google privacy policy.
The old one is using SMS and phone status permissions, now I created a new one without those permission with reduced functionality.
I want to publish this new version but with a new name or flavor, I don't know exactly that's why I'm here, to avoid the automatic app update of the current users.
So, the new users can download the new version and the old ones keep the full featured app.

At this moment I have cloned the old project and created the new version.
What precaution should I take to upload as new app?
Should I change the project name?
Change the apk key?
Create a new flavor?

I'm lost. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The app will auto-updated if you use the same release-key and package name. Then users get a new version of your app. And you can't control this inside of your app. Because permissions will be changed if users download the new app.

If you want to users couldn't update, you need to release as a new app. 
I'm following this question if there is any solution

long story short, I think your request is not possible.

Comment: You said "same release-key AND package name". So if I change one of those or bot it will be a new app? My users was happy until Google and their policies show up, what a pain in the....

Comment: Yes, I looked up new Google policies. Some of my friends deleted permissions from their apps. Btw your app can be deleted by Google if permission stays on your app.

Comment: Yes, Did you mean from PlayStore? My new App have not such permissions any more. It was a mess but I finally get a running App.

Comment: Yes, your current app will be deleted from Play Store. You can look at this [post][1].

They said `If the actual application name is also different, then the play store will treat it as two different apps.`



  
      [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216223/app-update-with-different-package-name-into-playstore

Comment: I get this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio to change the package name; wish me luck.

Comment: I'm just the developer, my boss is the one that upload the app to the PlayStore but seems like it worked because he didn't complain about.