# May I change the package name of my published app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an android app in the Google Play Store. I am working on a new rev and want to change the package name. Is that allowed?

My application does not have a big audience yet. Is there a way to replace it? As in, may I discontinue the existing one, and replace it with a new one?

Comment: A quick jog to the documentation should have given you enough insight: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) from Android Developers blog, no, you cannot change package name unless you're okay with publishing it as a new app in Play Store:

> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

Android manual confirms it as well [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html):

> Caution: Once you publish your application, you cannot change the
>   package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so
>   if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application
>   and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

---

If you're okay with publishing new version of your app as a completely new entity, you can do it of course - just remove old app from Play Store (if you want) and publish new one, with different package name.

Answer (score -6):

If you have the code, change the application package name, versionCode, versionName & update your app..

There is no otherway

Comment: your answer seems to contradict @kamitual above. I have updated my post. Will you please clarify?

Comment: @learner - it's `@kamituel` ;) I've updated my answer - you cannot change package name unless you're willing to publish it as a new app in Play Store (which you're fine with, I suppose, seeing your updated OP)