# Change package name after publishing

Tags: android, google-play, package

Some times ago I published an application on the Google Store, with a random package name because I didn't know what it was for at the time (I was a newbie to Android)
Now my app works, is installed on a number of devices, and I want to change this package name, since it seems it's used for ranking in search and such.

Is it possible to change the public package name of an application without creating a new application on the store?

Comment: no it is not possible. because if you change package name then change your url.

Comment: No It is not possible, it will search based on the package name.So key is package name only.So If you want to upload new package application then you can unpublished old application, and publish new application with correct package name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Things That Cannot Change:
>
> The most obvious and visible of these is the “manifest package name,”
>   the unique name you give to your application in its
>   AndroidManifest.xml. The name uses a Java-language-style naming
>   convention, with Internet domain ownership helping to avoid name
>   collisions. For example, since Google owns the domain “google.com”,
>   the manifest package names of all of our applications should start
>   with “com.google.” It’s important for developers to follow this
>   convention in order to avoid conflicts with other developers.
>
> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

More on things you cannot change [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

Comment: You should close question as duplicate instead of copy answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, Because package name is the unique identity of your app.  You need to create a new project with different package name and publish again in play store.