# When I change the package name, where else I have to change?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, push-notification, package, developer-console

First I **uploaded one app** with **one package** and now client **changed the package name**, in my app I used **FB login and push notifications** with the old app, so I have to change any thing in the **FB developer** either I have to create new account or I can use the **old fb developer account and app_ID**, with changing of the Package name.I am so much confused what I have to do, when I change the package name,please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to **change** the **folder names** to match the name of the new package.

**For example the package:**

xxx.yyy.zzz

**Should correspond to the directory:**

xxx/yyy/zzz

Comment: I changed the directory names also, any other changes in social connects developer accounts (FB) and google developer accounts

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with android development so I dont know what else could be causing the problem.. but have a look at these 2 links, I think they might be what you are looking for, good luck :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play
or
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760965

Answer (score 0):

First , In android code, you will need to change package names in manifest xml and gradle mainly. use refractor for that.

secondly,
you mentioned that you used fb login and push notifications,
so for these, you will need to make some changes .
in Facebook developer app settings page, simple add your new package name to existing package list,
and for GCM push notifications, do the same on developer console and create new configuration  files and add them to your project and everything will work fine.

Comment: but without changing that also my app working, so is it mandatory to change, what makes difference

Comment: Can anyone answer for this question because my app is also working with FB and GPlus login after changing the package name.
Do i need to create new configuration file?