# Can I use 'com.google.android.gm.Myapp' as applicationId for my Android app?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to change my `applicationId` to `com.google.android.gm.Myapp` in my app gradle or any other package like `com.facebook.Myapp` etc...
I would like to know what are the consequences of this changing.

Generally, I can do it and everything look work the same,
but maybe later i won't be able to upload my app to google developer console?
or maybe i will have an issues with implementation of google libs?

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play

Comment: It's not my question. My manifest is with my unique package 'com.myurl.myapp'. I asked about changing the app gradle 'applicationId' in the section of defaultConfig

Comment: Moreover, I didn't publish it yet. so for now i can change it how much i want. I just asked about use 'com.google' before i try to publish it.

Comment: Fair enough, when you wrote "I want to change it" I understood you want to do it for an existing app, not a new app. Anyway the information in the other answer is relevant to `applicationId` set in gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be abe to publish the APK with `com.facebook` and `com.whatsapp`

[image: Facebook example]

---

You will **not** be able to publish your APK to the Play Store if your package name contains `com.google`.

I just tested it with a simple debug APK, this was the result:

[image: Publishing exception]

> You need to use a different package name because 'com.google' is restricted.

And, yes, there is always a small chance that your package name creates a conflict with Google's libraries.

Comment: Did you try it by changed the manifest package or the gradle applicationId package?

Comment: Gradle's applicationId attribute, I set it to 'com.google.android.gm.Myapp'

Comment: Ohhh... just com.google is restricted but any other like com.facebook/com.whatsapp aren't. So I can use them is it correct?

Comment: Your questions are so worrying.. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to set my default applicationId com.someapp.mysubapp then i will get intents from apps that send intent to spesific packages.