# Update app after changing the package name in google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, package-name

I was changing the package name of my app by the code.

I can't changing it back because other feature.

Theres anything to do with that in google play console without opening it from the beginning?

Thank you

**update**
there wasn't any solution for this, I had to change back the package name to the old one, other option is to create a new app

Comment: If you change package name, Google Play console will consider it as a different app. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)