# Same package on google play. Is it possible?

Tags: google-play

I have a question about google play link.

I've created an app that has the same name as other app. After I realised that app with such name already exists, I changed the name of app directory in Android Studio to other name. Link still contains the same name that other app with other package name, now I can't go back. Is it legal to use other app's name in google play link with my company domain? (after change name in app directory in Android Studio?).

Relevant information will helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on legality - you'd have to ask a lawyer for that, not a programming Q&A site. But it is always a good idea to make the package name of your app start with the reverse of the domain name that you own. For example, if you owned myfirstapp.com then make your app package name com.myfirstapp. This avoids clashes and problems like this. So for example GMail is com.google.android.gm because Google owns google.com.

You can't change the package name once you have created it. However in your case if you don't have many users already then I'd just create a new app with the new package name, and ask your users to move. If you already have thousands of users you might just have to live with your old package name. But I'd ask a lawyer.