# I used the wrong package name in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded my first app and realized I used the wrong package name. Now I'm wondering is there a way to change this?

Comment: No you cant change the package name: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17582289/5348018

Comment: Ah that sucks, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already published the app then No you cannot change the package name, but if it's not yet published you can just create a secondary application on the console with the right values