# Package name change in Google as new app on the same app

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I can see [there are answers to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

> if it is possible to change the package name in google console!

to be **NO**.

I also see people point out that the app with the new package name is considered as a new app. ***But what that means?***

My questions:

1. Can I upload a new .aab to the same app in google console with a
   different package name or not?

*Considering that it is OK for me if there will be two apps and the new one will be installed next to the old one if a user has already downloaded the old one and the new app won't update it. That is because my app is just released and there are not many users so I don't care. But I care about the package name in the app URL.*

2. What happens to the URL with the old package name after I push my
   app to production?

Comment: Simple answer for 1. is `NO` you can't upload .abb with different package name.

Comment: "I also see people point out that the app with the new package name is considered as a new app" -- by "package name", are you referring to the `applicationId`, such as what is set in Gradle? "But I care about the package name in the app URL" -- by "app URL", are you referring to a Play Store URL?

Comment: Both yes and yes. I need to change the applicationID so the google play URL would change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I upload a new .aab to the same app in google console with a
> different package name or not?

No, you can't publish a update over the previous app with changes package name/app id.

But can change the appId of your app (present in `build.gradle`), and publish it as a new release, but it will allow new app installed next to previous one which you mentioned you don't care about.(That is because my app is just released and there are not many users so I don't care. But I care about the package name in the app URL.)

> What happens to the URL with the old package name after I push my app
> to production?

If you mean url to play store , it will still navigate to old app if it exits on play store otherwise to a error page saying no app found or something similar

Comment: As "a new release" means add a new app to my developer account and go through the icon, screenshots and all the other forms required to be filled in? Or new release as if promoting the new .aab to production?

Comment: First one,  add a new app to my developer account.