# Google Play Console: Can I change the package name to the package name of another app on the same account?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, package-name

On the Google Play Console, I have two apps that have package names `com.package1` and `com.package2`. I want to change `com.package1` to `com.package2`. It doesn't matter to me what `com.package2` gets changed to. Is this possible? I know that you can change the package name of an app, but I'm wondering if you can change it to the name of another existing app on your account.

Comment: You shouldn't change the package name if your application is already published. Because then you can't release any updates. But if that is not the case, you can change the `com.package2` app package and then change the `package1` to `package2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play)

Comment: @KhalidSaifullahFuad They're both technically on the store, but neither has any users. We pushed them to the store in order to test whether they'd get approved, but we're not making it known to users yet. Can you explain more about not being able to release updates? If I changed `com.package2` to `com.package1`, would I then be able to release updates to the new `com.package1` after people have downloaded it?

Comment: If you change the name of a published app. Then google play will consider that app as a 'new' app. Yes, you can release updates to the new app if the user installs the new app.